# jcrop suddenly jumps in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

here is my page:
http://anashimyafim.co.il/join

you can click on the green button below,
you will be slided to another div,
where you should upload an image.

than after the image is uploaded I place it in the page,
and call the jcrop function.

than if I click on the image to crop it,
the divs are suddenly moving.

do you have any suggestions??